# MongoDB storing a circle

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to store a circle on MongoDB? I want to store circles as collections, and be able to index them for searching. I know that the `$geoWithin` query is possible where one specifies a circle and retrieves points or now GeoJSON objects, but I want to be able to do the opposite. Somehow drawing a giant polygon with multiple points on a plane doesn't seem very attractive as a workaround, so I'm hoping that someone has something better.

I've searched on Google, but can't find anything. I know about storing polygons and linestring, which were introduced in MongoDB 2.3>, there are also some suggestions on the GeoJSON spec for defining circles. 
I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982497/mongodb-geospatial-querying-within-shapes-in-collection) question on SO,but the OP never came back to link to jira, or to update the answer if they found a solution.